# Cucumber : how to convert object type to string for asList()?

Tags: java, cucumber

I'm using cucumber test in my Java project, and I have a feature which contains a datatable :

```
{"field1":a,"field2":1.2,"field3":9}
```

and this should be converted by the method `asList()` to an object of type `Map<String,String>`, but when I test it it says it cannot transform because the type is not good. So when I write like this :

```
{"field1":"a","field2":"1.2","field3":"9"}
```

there is no more problem. But I don't want to add quote to every line of my feature file, because there are many of them and I want to still write like the previous one, and find a solution to tell asList() if it's transforming a field of type `Map<String,String>`, it should do the conversion implicitly.

Is it possible ?

Comment: I believe that the first datatable is represented incorrectly. `"field":a`. Here `a` should be wrapped in quotes because it is a String. Then you need to change your map to have value of `Object` type because you have both strings and numbers for values.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to convert your object to Map<String, Object> first, and then convert each value in the map to String by using toString().